# How can I retrieve lightweight edges from OrientDB

Tags: java, orientdb

I am creating a graph using OrientGraphNoTx in order to achieve massive insertion. After the creation I want to test if everything went well by counting the amount of nodes and edges created. As far as I know the countEdges() function don't work because the lightweight feature is enabled. So I am trying to count the edges with some custom code:

```
int count = 0;
for(Edge edge : orientGraph.getEdges()) {
    count++;
}
```

This doesn't work either. I assume that getEdges() function doesn't work either with lightweight edges. So how can I retrieve lightweight edges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're really interested on browsing the edges you can disabling the lightweight edges at the cost to slow down everything. Or if it's just for test purpose you can do:

```
Set<Object> edges = new HashSet();
for(Vertex v : orientGraph.getVertices()) {
    for( Edge e : v.getEdges( Direction.BOTH ) )
      edges.add( e.getIdentity() );
}
return edges.size();
```

In this way you collect all the ids of all the edges (removing duplicates), and then return the edge's collection size.

Comment: Nice, it worked. I assume that you meant edges.add( e.getId() );